# Is there any way to use external libraries in WebStorm debugger?

Tags: node.js, debugging, settings, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to test my code with [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library, but WebStorm debugger doesn't recognize `import` statement of my code and throws `ReferenceError`.

Also it throws `SyntaxError` when I use `import` statement in the debugger console.

How can I use external libraries specified in my `package.json` file?

[image: debugging screenshot]

Comment: how do you tun your code? Do you transpile/bundle it in any way?

Comment: I use Typescript and don't make a bundle.
I use Mocha to write test codes and run them with green triangle button on the left side of WebStorm editor.
I'll attach WebStorm config or tsconfig file if you need.

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError errors while evaluating code in debugger must be caused by wrong/missing name mappings in sourcemaps: if the variable is renamed while transpiling/obfuscating, and no appropriate name mapping is provided, the debugger won't be able to match variable in source code with the one in VM.

For example, `import somefunction from './somefunc'` is usually compiled to

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var somefunc_1 = require("./somefunc");
somefunc_1.default();
```

and no name mappings are generated (`"names":[]` in generated sourcemap), so the debugger can't match the variable in `.ts` file with the code in runtime and shows undefined

Related ticket: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627